# Unexpected behavior when std::thread.detach is called

Tags: c++, linux

I've been trying to develop a better understanding of C++ threading, by which I have written the following example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Test {
 public:
  Test() { x = 5; }

  void act() {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    std::thread worker(&Test::changex, this);
    worker.detach();
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
  }

 private:
  void changex() {
    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
    x = 10;
    std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
  }

  int x;
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  t.act();

  return 0;
}
```

To me, I should get the following output when compiled with `g++` linked with `-pthread`:

```
1
2
3
4
```

as the `cout` calls are in that order. However, the output is inconsistent. 1 and 2 are always printed in order, but sometimes the 3 and or 4 are either omitted or printed double. *i.e. `12`, `123`, `1234`, or `12344`*

My working theory is that the main thread exits before the worker thread begins working or completes, thus resulting in the omission of output. I can immediately think of a solution to this problem in creating a global boolean variable to signify when the worker thread has completed that the main thread waits on for a state change before exiting. This alleviates the issue.

However, this feels to me like a highly messy approach that likely has a more clean solution, especially for an issue like this that likely comes up often in threading.

Comment: *main thread exits before the worker thread begins working or completes* extremely likely. Instead of a local thread and `detach`ing, consider making the thread a class member and `join`ing it in the `Test ` destructor. Not a perfect solution, but should prove your conjecture.

Comment: If you are trying to perform tasks asynchronously, consider [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) instead. It's easier and safer to use than `std::thread`.

Comment: "*creating a global boolean variable to signify when the worker thread has completed that the main thread waits on for a state change before exiting*" - you can use std::condition_variable` for that instead of a simple boolean.

Comment: This program  is prone to threads accessing destructed object (since your main can easily finish before your auxiliary thread). However, I can't really explain double printing of `4`. Are you sure you get this result with the snippet provided?

Comment: The use of `detach` is almost always a sign that there is a design problem. It's used to indicate that you do not care about when or even if the thread ever finishes it's work. But this is almost never true. You are considering a solution for detecting when the work becomes done (and thus, when it's safe to exit) which is contrary to what you express by using `detach`. Simply don't `detach` and instead `join` where it's appropriate.

Comment: @user4581301 How would that work? Doesn't `std::thread` start as soon as it is defined? The idea is to be able to start the thread on demand, without creating a new instance of the class.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes, that exact sample generates the described behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Interesting, I didn't think about it that way before...

Comment: A thread starts as soon as it is created with a function to run. If you create it with nothing to run and then assign over it later with a thread that DOES have something to run, bazinga!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how this could be done:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Test {
    std::thread worker; // worker is now a member
 public:
  Test() { x = 5; } // worker deliberately left without a function to run.
  ~Test()
  {
    if (worker.joinable()) // worker can be joined (act was called successfully)
    {
        worker.join(); // wait for worker thread to exit.
                       // Note destructor cannot complete if thread cannot be exited. 
                       // Some extra brains needed here for production code.
    }
  }

  void act() {
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    worker = std::thread(&Test::changex, this); // give worker some work
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
  }
 // rest unchanged.
 private:
  void changex() {
    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
    x = 10;
    std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
  }

  int x;
};

int main() {
  Test t;
  t.act();

  return 0;
} // test destroyed here. Destruction halts and waits for thread.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just some general advice, that holds both for using raw pthreads in C++ and for pthreads wrapped in std::thread: The best way to get readable, comprehensible and debuggable behavior is to make thread synchronization and lifetime management explicit. I.e. avoid using pthread_kill, pthread_cancel, and in most cases, avoid detaching threads and instead do explicit join.

One design pattern I like is using an std atomic flag. When main thread wants to quit, it sets the atomic flag to true. The worker threads typically do their work in a loop, and check the atomic flag reasonably often, e.g. once per lap of the loop. When they find main has ordered them to quit, they clean up and return. The main thread then join:s with all workers.

There are some special cases that require extra care, for example when one worker is stuck in a blocking syscall and/or C library function. Usually, the platform provides ways of getting out of such blocking calls without resorting to e.g. pthread_cancel, since thread cancellation works very badly with C++. One example of how to avoid blocking is the Linux manpage for getaddrinfo_a, i.e. asynchronous network address translation.

One additional nice design pattern is when workers are sleeping in e.g. select(). You can then add an extra control pipe between main and the worker. Main signals the worker to quit by send():ing one byte over the pipe, thus waking up the worker if it sleeps in select().